# Compiling C S-Function in MATLAB multiple definition error

Tags: c, matlab, compiler-errors, simulink, s-function

I am trying to compile various C-Functions in MATLAB Simulink using the S-function builder block and the minGW 64bit Compiler.
A syntax error in the code is impossible since it is code from an ECU which is in production and running for years.

I keep getting the following error message with two of my files:

> ...example.obj:example.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `example'
>
> ...example.obj:example.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here

The error confuses me since it is referring to the same position as the "first definition".
In the other functions it is position (`.text+0x17a`).

Has any of you guys faced the same problem or any idea how to fix it? Can it be a bug of the compiler?

Greetings from Germany,
Jonathan

Comment: Very likely you have 2 things named "example".

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Unfortunately not, I searched all files and the name is not in use anywhere else - except for the declaration of the external function above my main function and the function call itself.

Comment: Are those in the same file example.obj, or are there two files example.obj in different directories?

Comment: They are named differently ('example' was just a common spaceholder). I have a file example.c which I am compiling, thus it creates: example.obj. During this compilation I get the above mentioned error example.obj:example.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'example'.

Comment: Have you included the `example.c` in another `c` file of your project?

Comment: No, it is just declared as external function above the main function and called one time within the main function

Comment: I avoided the Problem by including the relevant parts of the mentioned c functions into my main program. I still could not figure out why the error occured. Nonetheless I want to thank you guys for your consideration.